# OpenCV VideoCapture() not opening video file

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, visual-c++

I like many others are failing to load a video file using the VideoCapture() class. I have created a VC++ project in Visual Studio 2022 and included the headers, libraries and the compiled dlls both debug and release into the build. It is building successfully and `imread()` is working fine, but no video file, irrespective of location (with or without spaces), string type (`std::string` vs `cv::String`), string format (`\\` vs `/` path separators), or codec, is opening successfully. I have used the base constructor (`const String`) and the `open()` method, both have the same result. The `isOpened()` method returns `false`.

Why could this be failing?

My `getBuildInfo` is as follows:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.9.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.9.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2023-12-28T00:05:53Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.19045 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.23.3
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 16 2019
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1928
    Configuration:               Debug Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (16 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (8 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (36 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.28.29334.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /wd4819 /MP  /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO 
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo stitching video videoio world
    Disabled:                    python3
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.3)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
      SIMD Support Request:      YES
      SIMD Support:              NO
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.5.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2021.11.0 [2021.11.0]
           at:                   C:/GHA-OCV-1/_work/ci-gha-workflow/ci-gha-workflow/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2021.11.0)
              at:                C:/GHA-OCV-1/_work/ci-gha-workflow/ci-gha-workflow/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
    Flatbuffers:                 builtin/3rdparty (23.5.9)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/GHA-OCV-1/_work/ci-gha-workflow/ci-gha-workflow/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python (for build):            C:/Python-3.9/python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         C:/apache-ant-1.9.15/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.9.15)
    Java:                        NO
    JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.9/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.9/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.9/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/GHA-OCV-1/_work/ci-gha-workflow/ci-gha-workflow/install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "string type (std::string vs cv::String)" -- in OpenCV 4.x they're the [same thing](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga1f6634802eeadfd7245bc75cf3e216c2)

Comment: Is the ffmpeg DLL that ships with OpenCV on the system path? Did you try to specify alternate VideoIO backends in the `VideoCapture` constructor?

Comment: @DanMašek opencv_worldxxx.dll opencv_worldxxxd.dll and opencv_videoio_ffmpeg490_64.dll are not not on the system path but is in the application subdirectory where my shim dll is. However, simply moving opencv_videoio_ffmpeg490_64.dll to the application folder directly has worked perfectly. Your question has been exactly what I needed and I feel silly.